# Make a file to act as tty with dup

Tags: c, linux, posix, pipe

Okay, so I have a problem. I must get the output of a program using the `execlp` and make the output go directly to a file. The problem is that the program only outputs certain information if it's running in a tty,(I guess it calls `isatty(3)`).
Here is my code so far

```
void main(){
    int fd = open("file", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0755);
    close(1);
    dup(fd);
    execlp("program","program",NULL);
    close(fd);
}
```

I don't want to use OS commands like `script` (which works) or so on.

So the question is, how can I "trick" the program into thinking that it is writing into a tty?

Comment: Use a "pty" (Pseudo Terminal) as output. [see this question][1] for details.


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21147/what-are-pseudo-terminals-pty-tty

Comment: And I wish SO wouldn't convert "trivial" answers to comments :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a "pty" (Pseudo Terminal) as output. [see this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21147/what-are-pseudo-terminals-pty-tty) for details.

Rachid Koucha wrote a lengthy article explaining the details how to work with ptys: [Using pseudo-terminals (pty) to control interactive programs](http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html)

**Stop reading** This text here just exists to stop the stupid SO algorithm to turn my answer into a comment. I hate it when software makes itself smarter than me :-(

Comment: Can you provide a little orientation of how I could include that into my code? Thanks

Comment: I've updated the second link: http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html